# <li> hover event on <div> inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the [AJAX control toolkits autocomplete](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx) in a really old project of mine. I have some problem with the mouseover highlighting.

In the example that works, the generated `<li>` tags gets a mouseover event which changes their background color using inline css. Works well. However, when i change the markup from:

```
<li>
    Hello world
</li>
```

to

```
<li>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>world</div>
</li>
```

The `<li>` element will only change background color when i hover a part of them which is not covered by one of the divs.

Since I can't modify the generated (and minified) javasacript, I'm looking for a quick and dirty fix.

I have tried to change the z-index of the elements, without success. I've also tried to find the event of the li and add it to the div. But I can't find a way to copy events that is not added by jquery to another element.

Any ideas here are much appreciated.

Below if the reverted minified javascript if its to any help:

```
_highlightItem: function(item) {   
    /// <summary>   
    /// Highlights the specified item   
    /// </summary>   
    /// <param name="item" type="Sys.UI.DomElement" DomElement="true" mayBeNull="false" />   
    /// <returns />   

    var children = this._completionListElement.childNodes;   

    // Unselect any previously highlighted item   
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {   
        var child = children[i];   
        if (child._highlighted) {   
            if (this._completionListItemCssClass) {   
                Sys.UI.DomElement.removeCssClass(child, this._highlightedItemCssClass);   
                Sys.UI.DomElement.addCssClass(child, this._completionListItemCssClass);   
            } else {   
                if (Sys.Browser.agent === Sys.Browser.Safari) {   
                    child.style.backgroundColor = 'white';   
                    child.style.color = 'black';   
                } else {   
                    child.style.backgroundColor = this._textBackground;   
                    child.style.color = this._textColor;   
                }   
            }   
            this.raiseItemOut(new AjaxControlToolkit.AutoCompleteItemEventArgs(child, child.firstChild.nodeValue, child._value));   
        }   
    }   

    // Highlight the new item   
    if(this._highlightedItemCssClass) {   
        Sys.UI.DomElement.removeCssClass(item, this._completionListItemCssClass);   
        Sys.UI.DomElement.addCssClass(item, this._highlightedItemCssClass);   
    } else {   
        if (Sys.Browser.agent === Sys.Browser.Safari) {   
            item.style.backgroundColor = 'lemonchiffon';   
        } else {   
            item.style.backgroundColor = 'highlight';   
            item.style.color = 'highlighttext';   
        }   

    }   
    item._highlighted = true;   
    this.raiseItemOver(new AjaxControlToolkit.AutoCompleteItemEventArgs(item, item.firstChild.nodeValue, item._value));   
},
```

Comment: you need to set the background of the `div` to transparent

Comment: Perhaps, could you place the div as inline elements or you need to have them one below each other. you could use span and br

Comment: perhaps, put a .on("mousover" on your divs, and let the event bubble up the DOM (with a transparent background on the divs) ?

Comment: @jbl Even if the background is transparent, the div would still take up its physical space, right? SO if I hover it, the li event won't trigger anyway.

Comment: the event will bubble-up and will be caught at your li's level. See this jsfiddle jsfiddle.net/z37c4 But I realize your problem seems to be with custom event which triggers _highlightItem and to which your divs need to subscribe

Comment: @jbl Yup, thanks though.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use CSS to add the needed highlights?

```
li > div:hover {
  /* Highlight Rule Here */
}
```

Comment: Since the rest of the highlight logic is located in the javascript, I'm afraid this won't work. The javascript will still highlight the wrong elements sometimes, while this moves on to the next div.

Comment: Why not unbind the highlight from JavaScript on the `li` all together and allow CSS to handle it? You can just copy the highlight styles into the new rule. I don't see the need for JavaScript to handle it.

Comment: The problem is that I can't modify the autogenerated javascript. And part of the logic involves that the highlighted item is the one that the user will be transferred to. So even if i fix the css somehow, the user would still end up on the wrong page.